# Manually managing a view distance in a game, but only selectively applying it to objects

Tags: optimization, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on an open world game so I have to optimize it quite a bit because there is a lot to render. In the game I am manually implementing a view distance so I can hide objects that are far away (to save on rendering time). However, I only want certain objects to be hidden like this.

To identify which objects should have this behaviour, I'm currently thinking of adding a new Static setting type (to the Static dropdown on a GameObject), so I can check whether the object has that Static setting and that it should be selectively rendered. Can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by a new...static? Static variable? Static method? Please clarify your question so we have a better understanding of your thought process here.

Comment: What do you mean by 'static' and by 'making view distance'? Are you trying to limit view distance for the player? In that case using layers + camera properties should be enough.

Comment: I mean the part of the Static check box in the Inspector window in Unity

Comment: Its up to you of course, but I wouldnt rely on that 'Static' feature. Maybe I don`t know something incredibly important about it, but for me it seems completely useless. If you want to have access from your class to some static object, you can use static classes. Can you desribe what you want to achieve by using static object? Perhaps we can find better way around.

Comment: I want to check only some objects as a ViewDistance Static that I would call the new static and only those objects would get affected by the ViewDistance. I would use this for eg. trees in the distance. Some would be rendered but some wouldn't and I can check them to be static. And I don't want to create a script for that because almost every object in the game would have to load the script to which lowers performance.

Comment: Are you instantiating these static GameObjects, or are they already in place when the game starts?

Comment: They are already in place but wont render if they aren't in the view distance. Also there are 3 render modes. Instant, slow and fast. Instant instantly renders objects when the game starts. Fast makes the view distance grow until it reaches the view distance it is set to at a fast past and slow is same as fast but at a slow paste

Comment: Also, for some reason, this works: GameObject.FindWithTag("environment").GetComponent.<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you're talking about. You're asking whether you can add a new type of setting to the Static dropdown? I don't think that's modifiable. Rather than that, how about creating a trigger collider around the player, and enabling/disabling environmental objects/renderers (identified via layer, tag, or class - whatever flexibility you need) as they enter/leave the collider? That's one way you can simulate draw distance selectively.

Comment: I did that but I want some objects to not be affected by that by adding a new static to them

Comment: How about adding a class to them instead, and run `GetComponent()` to see whether they have it? (Since, as I said, I don't think you can change the options listed in the Static dropdown.) You can further narrow down how they behave by adding an enum to the class should that be needed. This will also give you more flexibility in the future if you want to program GameObjects transitioning in rather than popping in.

Comment: I'll do that with the scripts. Just hope I don't lose performance. You should post the answer so I can give you a tick and a vote up :)

Comment: Sure thing! Answer added. Glad I could help out, hope you're able to get it working for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the options available to you in the Static dropdown - those are built into the Unity engine. However, there's no need to, as you have a plethora of other options for identifying objects.

You seem to have already tried using a Tag, but have indicated that you need more flexibility than that - so I suggest adding a class to any environmental objects you want to be affected by this selective view distance. Then, add a trigger collider around your player object, and run `GetComponent()` to identify environmental objects as they enter the collider. Enable the objects/renderers as they enter the collider, and disable them as they leave it.

For additional flexibility, you can add an `enum` to the class so you can have environmental objects behave differently when they enter the player's trigger collider - for example, if you're eventually animating in the objects (rather than popping them in), you might want one to fade in from transparent, while another pops up from the ground, etc.

**Edit:**

An alternative approach that I looked up is the [`Camera.layerCullDistances`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-layerCullDistances.html) variable, which allows you to set different distances at which the camera will render layers. Depending on your requirements, this can also work for you - for example, terrain may be on one layer while trees are on another, so at long distances you could could still keep terrain visible, but not vegetation.

This approach should be cheaper than the class/collider-based approach, so it's handy if you're targeting mobile devices. Not (arguably) the best approach if you have stronger hardware available to you though, since objects will pop in/out and you won't be able to smooth their transition into visibility.